# Parse.com JS SDK Multiple Queries Inside Loop

Tags: parse-platform

thanks in advance for your help.

I have a situation where I need to execute several queries inside a loop using the Parse JS SDK Queries.

As we know, sometimes Parse behaves asyncronously.

The query goes like this:

1) Make a query to a table and find some records (This works).
2) For each record found, get a property that contains one ID of an object from another table (This works).
3) For each of those ID's, make a query, where you get info from another table (Here is the problem).

I have tryied several ways to try to make all the queries in a loop and try to sync the last query in order to make a response.success with the desired data, but so far I have not been able.

Do you have any idea about how to do syncronously several queries inside a loop by using the Parse JS SDK?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the suggested approach for this.

Comment: Hey Dano007, I'm still working on a workarround for this. As soon as I have it solved I will post the solution here. The core of the problematic function can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jpruiz114/QTw6U/1/

Answer (score 3):

Using [Parse.Promise](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html) is the easiest way to coordinate between multiple asynchronous requests.

```
// build an array of queries
var queries = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    // construct the query and kick it off
    var q = new Parse.Query().find();
    queries.push(q);
}

// Wait for them all to complete
Parse.Promise.when(queries).then(function() {
    // the results of each query are returned as arguments to the callback
    for(var i=0, l=arguments.length; i<l; i++) {
        // process each result
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks in advance. This is my code right now:

http://jsfiddle.net/jpruiz114/QTw6U/

Obviously there's a Parse.Cloud.define before all of this. That is just the core of the function. I don't know if I am doing something wrong (Most likely) but this code is not working.

Could you please guide me?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like relational queries. You could fire the last query using matchesQuery. See this example:

```
var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
var Comment = Parse.Object.extend("Comment");
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Post);
innerQuery.exists("image");
var query = new Parse.Query(Comment);
query.matchesQuery("post", innerQuery);
query.find({
  success: function(comments) {
    // comments now contains the comments for posts with images.
  }
});
```

Instead of firing your first query, use it in the matchesQuery constraint on your second query. So, instead of iterating through the returned objects and getting the IDs, you could probably use dot notation to get the ids and use that in your second query.

Comment: Hi there, thanks in advance for the help. This is not the kind of query I'm trying to do. Here I uploaded the main core of my function in Parse:

http://jsfiddle.net/jpruiz114/QTw6U/1/

As you will see, I need to get some ids first from a table, and then, for each of those id's get more data that can't be just crossed with the Parse native functions. There's some Geolocation logic envolved using the Parse.GeoPoint object.

If you have any idea on how to guide me, I would appreciate your asistance.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Handsomeguy - In your example, how can I get Posts given certain Comments?